# Stack size check during run time in C

Tags: c

Is there any performant tool that checks the size of the stack for each task during runtime.

I'm using OSEK/VDX compliant OS.

The only way that I see now is to implement a function that checks the stack "used vs free" for a given task basing on a filled pattern then send the result over Ethernet protocol. But I prefer to use a tool if it is available.

Answer (score 0):

If you think you might be strapped for stack space, you will almost certainly be limited by virtual memory. If you have to ask, you're probably doing something wrong.

But if you must know, you may use [getrusage](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getrusage.2.html), to get runtime usage per process (or child process), and [getrlimit](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/vlimit.3.html) to get system limits on linux.